# Subprocess post-installation script for install-info returned an error after installing Teamviewer

Tags: apt, dpkg

Recently I tried installing [Teamviewer7](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx) on my Ubuntu 12.04. I tried downloading the deb which due to some reason never did finish its download (stopped at ~10MB/17MB).

Expectedly, installing the same gave unmet dependencies. I followed instructions given

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

These are to my memory the only changes I made to the system. Following this, my `apt-get` or `dpkg` seem to be broken.

Following is a sample call which returns errors in subprocesses. (specially not: dpkg and install-info)

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up install-info (4.13a.dfsg.1-8ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst: 32: /var/lib/dpkg/info/install-info.postinst: update-info-dir: not found
dpkg: error processing install-info (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also, my Synaptic Package Manager and Google Chrome (if that's of any consequence) are not opening at all while Firefox et al seems to be working in order.

I tried out many things. A few suggestions included replacing `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file with a copy from a working version. This I believe might correct the broken dependencies. However I do not have a working copy accessible at the moment (not unless I create a bootable).

I really need some way to roll back the system to the previous state (backup doesn't work either).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the process had removed Bash from the system.
If you have the same problem, follow the instructions [here](https://www.phz.fi/2011/11/13/debian-install-info-postinst-update-info-dir-not-found/).

The basic procedure is as follows:

Go to the directory:

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives
```

Find the corresponding deb for bash. On 12.04, it may look like

```
bash_4.2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

After my failed attempt to install Teamviewer7, my system was not just missing bash, but when I attempted to manually install bash from a manually downloaded deb package, I got an error about a missing dependency: base-files.

I used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install base-files
```

This install completed successfully. Afterwards, I closed the terminal and reopened it and the various bash features (including the history) came back.