# Problems installing mysql on 18.04

Tags: dpkg, 18.04, mysql

I am new to ubuntu and trying to set up mysql. However when I run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

I get this  output that ends in an error code:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core- 
5.7
Suggested packages:
libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client
mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server
mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 9,820 B/20.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 160 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 
mysql-client all 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1 [9,820 B]
Fetched 9,820 B in 0s (373 kB/s)         
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME: not found
dpkg: error processing package install-info (--configure):
installed install-info package post-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
install-info
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Am I missing a step in the install process? What can I do to fix this error and get mysql installed?

Comment: Are you sure there's not more to that error?  Normally it would have spat out other error data...

Comment: Your problem seems to be something like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/203966/subprocess-post-installation-script-for-install-info-returned-an-error-after-ins

Comment: I updated the post with full output

Comment: I'm not sure this is the same problem that @Kulfy links to. In your case, a previous install of the package `install-info` hasn't finished correctly. Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` first; if that doesn't work remove `install-info` and try again.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and none of the solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your problem lies in the `/etc/environment` file? Can you show the contents of that file? The error seems to indicate you have a JAVA_HOME command instead of a setting.

Comment: I don't understand how you conclude that the problem is in the </etc/environment> file?  Could you please explain?

Comment: It says so in the error message:
`Setting up install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
/usr/sbin/update-info-dir: 2: /etc/environment: JAVA_HOME: not found`

Comment: Ahhh, somehow missed that...

Answer (score 0):

I also had many problem with both MySQL and MariaDB (ubuntu 18.04). I could not get MariaDB to work. I used both instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573787/how-to-forcefully-remove-mysql-and-mariadb-from-ubuntu-16-04-without-apt-get

```
$ dpkg --list|grep -i mysql
```

and

```
$ dpkg --list|grep -i mariadb
```

$ dpkg -remove --force-remove-reinstreq

Then installed MySQL as described at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Works well now, even after reboot.